# How to create a simple Prompt BattleShip Game in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to make a battleship game in JS with Prompt and I cant for the life of Me figure it out.
Example is attached: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSpJLx72PQY
Quality isnt very good
Here is some code

```
// BattleShip Grid
let grid = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"];
// Ship Locations
let shipLocations = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19"];
// Hit Locations
let hit = ["3", "9", "15"];
let enterNumber = "Enter a Number Between 0-19";
// Prompts First Guess
let guess = prompt(grid + '\n' + (enterNumber));
// Checks if there is a HIT
if(hit.indexOf(guess) !== -1){
        grid[guess] = "1";
        prompt(grid + '\n' + (enterNumber));
//Checks for Miss
    } else{
        grid[guess] = "X";
        prompt(grid + '\n' + (enterNumber));
    }
```

Needs to be

```
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```

Every time a hit happens the 0 where the hit happens becomes a 1 and if a miss it becomes an X and needs to update in the prompt. Hope someone can help. Was using an array. If someone could give me the answer so I can look it over and understand it would be great. Im very new

Hit

```
0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```

Miss

```
0 0 0 0 0 
0 X 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```

Updates

```
0 0 0 1 0 
0 X 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```

UPDATE credit to  julien.giband

New code, how do I get it to show a grid of 20 so 5 x 4?

```
const GRID_SIZE = 5;


const grid = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"];
// Ship Locations
const shipLocations = ["3", "9", "15"];
let guess; //Entered value
let count = 0; //counter for rounds
do { //We'll loop indefintely until the user clicks cancel on prompt

  //Construct prompt using string template (multiline)
  const prpt = `Round #${++count}
${printGrid()}
Enter a Number Between 0-19`;
  guess = prompt(prpt);
  if (!guess && guess !== 0)
    break; //Stop when cancel was clicked
  
  const hit = shipLocations.indexOf(guess) >= 0;
  console.log(`At round ${count}, cell ${guess} is a ${hit ? 'hit': 'miss'}`);
  grid[guess] = hit ? '1' : 'X';
} while (guess || guess === 0); //Must have an exit condition

/** Pretty-print the grid **/
function printGrid() {
  let res = "";
  for (let r = 0; r < GRID_SIZE; r++) {
    let srow = "";
    for (let c = 0; c < GRID_SIZE; c++) {
      srow += " " + grid[r * GRID_SIZE + c];
    }
    res += srow.substr(1) + '\n';
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: I’ll try to take a swing at this in the morning.

Comment: As you know battleship has 5 variations of ships. You don't seems to have that defined. As of now, you'd know a choice is a hit or a miss only. Also, the video you've linked seems to be private.

Comment: @MathewHarrison, where's your problem exactly ? Your code seems to work.. For a single turn anyway and prompting the array on one line. Is that the problem ? And your youtube video is private !

Comment: I need to loop forever until cancel the prompt, i set ot unlisted now not private

Comment: Readers here will expect you do describe _expected results_ vs _actual results_, Put some effort into isolating the problem, identify your areas of understanding and potential misunderstanding, and then and reduce the amount of code required to demonstrate the problem.  Your question is "how do I get it to show a grid of 20 so 5 x 4?", and it's not clear from the question what the current actual behaviour is or why you think your code doesn't do that.  You can also use runnable snippets right here in the question to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
//Grid size: result will be n*n cells
const GRID_SIZE = 5;

// BattleShip Grid (filled with 0s)
const grid = new Array(GRID_SIZE * GRID_SIZE);
grid.fill('0');
// Ship Locations
const shipLocations = [];
//Set test ship locations to first 3 rows fully filled
for (let i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE * 3; i++) {
  shipLocations.push("" + i);
}

let guess; //Entered value
let count = 0; //counter for rounds
do { //We'll loop indefintely until the user clicks cancel on prompt

  //Construct prompt using string templates
  guess = prompt( `Round #${++count}\n` +
                  `${printGrid()}\n` +
                  `Enter a Number Between 0-${GRID_SIZE * GRID_SIZE - 1}`);
  if (!guess && guess !== 0)
    break; //Stop when cancel was clicked
  
  const hit = shipLocations.indexOf(guess) >= 0;
  console.log(`At round ${count}, cell ${guess} is a ${hit ? 'hit': 'miss'}`);
  grid[guess] = hit ? '1' : 'X';
} while (guess || guess === 0); //Must have an exit condition

/** Pretty-print the grid **/
function printGrid() {
  let res = "";
  for (let r = 0; r < GRID_SIZE; r++) {
    let srow = "";
    for (let c = 0; c < GRID_SIZE; c++) {
      srow += " " + grid[r * GRID_SIZE + c];
    }
    res += srow.substr(1) + '\n';
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: this is helpful but alot of jQuery, thanks

Comment: @MathewHarrison There's no jQuery here. It's plain JavaScript

Comment: @MathewHarrison Oh I see: you see a $ symbol and assume jQuery. It's not, it's string templates, pure JavaScript. Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: So edited the code, see above I added new code with an update as was too long for here.
How do I go about making a 20 grid so 5 x 4?

Comment: @MathewHarrison it wouldn't kill you to give credit in your edit. just define two constants for rows and columns and use them wherever required instead of `GRID_SIZE`. You should ask a second question for that anyway. Think of other people that will come to an edited question and answers about the pre-edit version. What will they understand and learn ?

Comment: Thats a good point, I gave credit. I will ask that in another question, thank you, very helpful!

Comment: make an new question, will come back and  update the answer here once I get it all done, thanks for the big help.

Comment: @MathewHarrison great. Hope you got your definite answer there. Can you please remove your edit at the bottom of your post and rather rephrase your initial question with something along lines of "How can I make this work in a loop?", or whatever you deem was the actual point?

Answer (score 1):

I made an engine like class of my own. It sports a scalable map, ships of different orientations and sizes, as well as random ship positioning.

```js
//////////////////////
// GLOBAL VARIABLES //
//////////////////////

let game = new Battleship(6, 5) //Change map size here
let theShips={
    A: 3, // ID:size
    B: 2, // feel free to add more ships
    C: 4,
    D: 1
  }

let map = []
let round = 0
let note = ''
let moves = []

///////////////
// FUNCTIONS //
///////////////

function newmap() {
  let size = game.size
  map = []
  moves = []
  round = 0
  game.newmap()
  while (size--) {
    map.push(' _ ')
  }
}

function show(msg, arr) {
  let display = `${msg} \n`
  for (let y = 0; y < game.y; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < game.x; x++)
      display += `${arr[ x + (game.x*y) ]} `
    display += '\n'
  }
  return display
}

function watch(bool, msg) {
  if (bool) console.log(msg, 'successful!')
  else console.log(msg, 'failed!')
  return bool
}

function makeGuess(guess) {
  let ret = false
  let valid
  if (guess.toLowerCase().trim() == 'exit') ret = true
  guess = parseInt(guess)
  valid = 0 < guess < game.size
  if (valid && !moves.includes(guess)) {
    moves.push(guess)
    if (game.checkPosition(guess)) ret = hit(guess)
    else miss(guess)
    round++
  }
  return ret
}

function hit(position) {
  let sunk = game.hitShip(position)
  map[position] = ' O ' // When a ship is hit it will appear as an 'O'
  note = "It's a HIT!!!"
  return !game.checkShip(sunk) ? sunkShip(sunk) : false
}

function miss(position) {
  map[position] = ' X ' // When a ship is missed guess will appear as an 'X'
  note = "It's a miss!"
  return false
}

function sunkShip(id) {
  note = 'You sunk a ship'
  game.ships.splice(game.ships.indexOf(id), 1)
  return game.ships.length < 1
}

function newRandomMap(battleships) {
  for (let ships in battleships)
    while (true)
      if (watch(game.placeShip(ships, random(game.size), battleships[ships], random(2) ? 'horizontal' : 'vertical'), `Ship '${ships}' placement`)) break;
}

function random(num) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * num)
}

function init() {
  newmap() // make a map
  newRandomMap(theShips)
}

function startGame() {
  while (true) {
    if (makeGuess(prompt(promptMSG()))) break;
  }
  if (game.ships.length < 1) alert('You successfully sunk all the ships!!!')
}

function promptMSG() {
  return `note:Type 'exit' to stop\nRound#${round} ${show(note,map)}Pick a number from 0 to ${game.size-1}`
}

////////////////
// INITIALIZE //
////////////////

init()
//console.log(game.ships)
//console.log(show('Hidden',game.map))
//console.log(show('Make the first move',map))
startGame()
```

```html
<script>
////////////
// ENGINE //
////////////

class Battleship { // engine by StepPen-codes
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.size = x * y
    this.map = []
    this.ships = []

    this.newmap()
  }
  newmap() {
    let i = this.size
    this.ships = [] // reset ships array
    while (i--)
      this.map[i] = "0" //resets map array
  }
  hitShip(position) {
    let id = this.map[position]
    this.map[position] = "0"
    return id
  }
  checkShip(id) {
    return this.map.includes(id)
  }
  checkPosition(position) {
    return this.map[position] != "0"
  }
  placeShip(id, position, size, orientation = 'horizontal') {
    let posY = Math.floor(position / this.x)
    let posX = position % this.x
    let placed = false

    if (!this.ships.includes(id)) {
      switch (orientation) {
        case 'horizontal':
          if (size + posX <= this.x) {
            placed = this.setShip(id, position, size, 1)
          }
          break;
        case 'vertical':
          if (size + posY <= this.y) {
            placed = this.setShip(id, position, size, this.x)
          }
          break;
      }
      if (placed) this.ships.push(id) // setting ship is successful include ship in ships
    }
    return placed
  }
  setShip(id, position, size, adjustment) {
    let ship = [],
      ret = true
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      let pos = position + (i * adjustment)
      if (!this.checkPosition(pos)) ship.push(pos)
      else {
        ret = false
        break;
      }
    }
    if (ret)
      for (let i of ship) this.map[i] = id
    return ret
  }
}
</script>
```

Here it is:

- hosted https://steppen-playground.netlify.app/battleship-engine/
- github https://github.com/StepPen-codes/playground